# Iterating over two lists with certain condition

Tags: python

I have two lists, let's say

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

The condition is, that "A" in list2 relates to first 2 numbers in list1, "B" - to the next to numbers, "C" - to the all left numbers.

I try to create loop for these two lists so that as a result I could get the following:

```
1, A  
2, A  
3, B  
4, B
5, C  
6, C  
7, C
```

I thought of using "for i in list1[:n]" construction where n - number of elements, but I cannot predefine n since the amount of elements in list1 that belong to the last element in list2 is unknown.

Here is my attempt:

```
s=0
n=2
for i in l1:
    for t in l2[s:n]:
        print (i,t)  
        s+=2
        n+=2
```

Comment: Why is the amount of elements in list1 that belong to the last element in list2 unknown? Isn't it just `len(list1) - 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve that:

```
n = 2
# this is just the known length
res = [(y, x) for i, x in enumerate(list2) for y in list1[n*i:n*i+n]]
# just add the remaining items
res += [(x, list2[-1]) for x in list1[n*len(list2):]]
for x in res:
  print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2, 3,4, 5,6,7]
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]

items_to_iterate_on_list1_for_each_in_list2 = 2

index1 = 0
for item2 in list2:
    # We iterate for each element in list 2
    # on two elements of list 1
    for offset in range(items_to_iterate_on_list1_for_each_in_list2):
        print(f'{list1[index1 + offset]}, {item2}')
    index1 += items_to_iterate_on_list1_for_each_in_list2

# If there are elements remaining in list1, we iterate over them with last element of list2
for i in range(index1, len(list1)):
    print(f'{list1[i]}, {item2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]
for j,i in enumerate(list1):
    if j<2: print(list2[0],',',i)
    elif j<4: print(list2[1],',',i)
    else : print(list2[2],',',i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of index ranges that are to be used with slicing, and you can have `None` meaning the end of the list, so that the last slice is just however many items are left:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]

ranges = [(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, None)]

for r, letter in zip(ranges, list2):
    for i in list1[slice(*r)]:
        print(f'{i}, {letter}')
```

This gives

```
1, A
2, A
3, B
4, B
5, C
6, C
7, C
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution similiar to your code:

```
list1 = [1,2, 3,4, 5,6,7]
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]

items_to_iterate_on_list1_for_each_in_list2 = 2

s=0
n=2
for index2, item2 in enumerate(list2):
    index1 = index2 * n
    for t in list1[index1:index1 + n]:
        print(f'{t}, {item2}')

# Adjust to last index1
index1 += n

# If there are elements remaining in list1, we iterate over them with last element of list2
for i in range(index1, len(list1)):
    print(f'{list1[i]}, {item2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    index = min(i // 2, 2)
    print(f"{list1[i]}, {list2[index]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to associate each item of list2 with every 2 items from list1. In case where the number of elements in list1 is more than 6, any element after 6th position (or index 5) will be associated with the last element of list2. Here is my approach:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
list2 = ["A", "B", "C"]

for item in list1:
    try:
        print(item, list2[list1.index(item)//2])
    except:
        print(item, list2[-1])
```

Comment: What happens if you try it with `list1 = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3]`?

Comment: You can fix this though: instead relying on `list1.index(item)` you could make use of `enumerate`.